# How to find list of all tfvars variables which are not used in Terraform code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

### s3.tfvars

```
bucket = "first-bucket"
acl="private"
env = "dev"
owner = "abc@def.com"
var1 = "unused variable"
```

### s3.tf

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "abucket" {
  bucket = var.bucket 
  acl = "private"

  tags = {
    Environment = var.env
    Owner = var.owner
  }
}
```

var1 is not used in my code even though it is declared in tfvars as shown above.

When I run the following command

```
terraform plan -var-file=s3.tfvars
```

..., I get the following warning message:

```
Warning: Value for undeclared variable

The root module does not declare a variable named "var1" but a value was
found in file "s3.tfvars". To use this value, add a "variable" block to the
configuration.
```

Is there a way to capture this warning as an error? Or is there Any other way to find out list of all unused variables?

Comment: You can use a linter like [tflint](https://github.com/terraform-linters/tflint). For unsused variables there is a corresponding issue open [Unused variables in Terraform Files #11412](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/11412)

Comment: I tried tflint. But didn't help. Would you mind sharing the syntax how to run tflint for this particular use case please?

Comment: I see the support is there [tflint](https://github.com/terraform-linters/tflint/search?q=tfvar&type=commits). But using `tflint --var-file=s3.tfvars` doesnt complain though.

Answer (score 9):

You want to use [tflint](https://github.com/terraform-linters/tflint).

```
mkdir test/
cd test/
echo 'variable "what" {}' > main.tf
```

Add `.tflint.hcl`

```
rule "terraform_unused_declarations" {
  enabled = true
}
```

```bash
$ tflint --init
$ tflint
1 issue(s) found:

Warning: variable "what" is declared but not used (terraform_unused_declarations)

  on main.tf line 1:
   1: variable "what" {}

Reference: https://github.com/terraform-linters/tflint/blob/v0.28.1/docs/rules/terraform_unused_declarations.md
```

Comment: Is there a way to run all Rules throung one command?

Comment: @vasil001 https://github.com/terraform-linters/tflint/blob/master/docs/user-guide/config.md